# How to express a piecewise linear function in an open source solver

Tags: python, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

In my optimisation problem, unit cost varies by distance (rather distance buckets). As an example:

```
from to unit_cost total_cost_from total_cost_to
[[0, 174, 25, 0, 4350],
 [174, 281, 27, 4350, 7239],
 [281, 398, 29, 7239, 10632],
 [398, 533, 31, 10632, 14817],
 [533, 636, 32, 14817, 18113]]
```

so for between 174 to 281 units of distance, unit cost = 27

So if in the optimal solution say, distance takes the value 180, then `total cost =  174*25 + (180-174)*27 = 4512`

I am aware that many commercial solvers have piecewise functionality already incorporated in their APIs, but how can I achieve the same by an open source solver

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can formulate piecewise linear function in an open source solver. We will introduce additional variables, one for each break-point in the function. Assuming that we have `n` brackets, conceptually we consider these variables as weights on the bracket boundaries, telling us where we are in the bracket. We want at most two consecutive variables to be non-zero, with their sum to be one.

This will tell us where x lies and, consequently, what is the objective function value.

Below is the formulation in Google-ortool's linear solver.

```py
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

data = [
    [0, 174, 25, 0, 4350],
    [174, 281, 27, 4350, 7239],
    [281, 398, 29, 7239, 10632],
    [398, 533, 31, 10632, 14817],
    [533, 636, 32, 14817, 18113],
]

s = pywraplp.Solver("", pywraplp.Solver.CBC_MIXED_INTEGER_PROGRAMMING)
n = len(data)

# this is the final quantity selected
x = s.NumVar(data[0][0], data[n - 1][0], "x")

# introduce additional variables, one for each break-point in the function
# weights on the bracket boundaries, telling us where we are in the bracket
w = [s.NumVar(0, 1, "w[%i]" % (i,)) for i in range(n)]

# z is the set of binary variables whose only purpose is to
# enforce the SOS2 conditions over w's
z = [s.BoolVar("") for i in range(n)]

# We want the sum of the w's to be one
s.Add(1 == sum(w[i] for i in range(n)))

# calculation of x weighted sum of across brackets
# if say, w2 = 0.25 and w3 = 0.75, then we know that we are in the third bracket,
# x = w2 * point2 + w3 * point3
s.Add(x == sum(w[i] * data[i][0] for i in range(n)))

# put a constraint to determine the value of x
# since we will minimise cost (later) x will be forced to 180
# in optimal solution
# challenge is to identify the correct pair of brackets where 145 will lie
s.Add(x >= 180)

# Below constraints enforce SOS2 condition
# SOS2 : at most two consecutive variables to be non-zero

# There exists an order, in other words the variables can be sorted along one of their attributes
# They are all positive and continuous
# At most 2 of them are non-zero
# The two variables have to be adjacent

# above conditions are translated into code below
for i in range(n):
    s.Add(w[i] <= z[i])

s.Add(sum(z[i] for i in range(n)) <= 2)

# only adjacent z's can attain a value of 1
z_sum = {}
for i in range(n - 2):
    z_sum[i] = s.IntVar(0, 2, "")
    s.Add(z_sum[i] == z[i] + z[i + 1])

z_sum_bool = {i: s.BoolVar("") for i in range(n - 2)}

for i in range(n - 2):
    s.Add(z_sum[i] >= -2 * (1 - z_sum_bool[i]) + 2)

s.Add(sum(z_sum_bool[i] for i in range(n - 2)) == 1)

# minimize cost
cost = s.Sum(w[i] * data[i][3] for i in range(n))
s.Minimize(cost)
s.Solve()
R = [w[i].SolutionValue() for i in range(n)]
```

`w[I]` results in `[0.0, 0.94392523364486, 0.05607476635514003, 0.0, 0.0]`

which implies that 180 distance lies in `second to third` bracket or between `174 - 281`.

`s.Objective().Value()` = `4512` which is nothing but `174*25 + (180-174)*27`

Answer (score 0):

In [`PuLP`](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/) we can create a variable for each interval and set their bounds accordingly:
Data:

```py
breakpoints = [0, 174, 281, 398, 533, 636]
slopes = [25, 27, 29, 31, 32]

interval_lengths = [breakpoints[i+1] - breakpoints[i] for i in range(len(breakpoints)-1)]
```

Model:

```py
from pulp import *

prob = LpProblem("PiecewiseLinearVariables", LpMinimize)
x=LpVariable('x', lowBound=180,upBound=180, cat='Continuous')
variables = {}

# Create a variable for each interval, set its bounds to the respective interval length
for i in range(0,len(interval_lengths)):
    segment = f"Segment_{i+1}"
    variables[segment] = LpVariable(segment, lowBound=0,upBound=interval_lengths[i], cat='Continuous')
#Force the segments to take on values
prob += x==lpSum(var for var in variables.values())
#Add the weighted cost to the objective
prob + = lpSum(slope * var for var, slope in zip(variables.values(), slopes))

prob.solve()
```

Solution:

```py
for var in variables.values():
    print(f"{var.name}: {var.varValue}")
print(f"x: {value(x)}")
```

Output:

```
Optimal - objective value 4512 # From model.solve() output
Segment_1: 174.0
Segment_2: 6.0
Segment_3: 0.0
Segment_4: 0.0
Segment_5: 0.0
x: 180.0
```

No SOS or binary variables are required, which should generally result in a simpler model.

Answer (score 0):

For many classes of problem (you haven't specified), binary assignment variables aren't needed - @SebastianWozny has recognized this, but it's important to understand *why*.

Your incremental costs increase monotonically. For a cost minimization problem, it will always by its nature fill up lower buckets before upper buckets. If your incremental costs change so that they aren't monotonic this will not work. Likewise, if for whatever reason you want to maximize the amount of budget spent, this will not work.

Simplify away the total cost from and total cost to columns. Also, it's unclear why there should be a final maximum on distance: shouldn't the last row's incremental price apply to all distances above it?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pulp

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [  0, 25],
        [174, 27],
        [281, 29],
        [398, 31],
        [533, 32],
    ],
    columns=['from', 'unit_cost'],
)


def make_distance(row: pd.Series) -> pulp.LpVariable:
    return pulp.LpVariable(
        name=f'distance_{row.name}',
        lowBound=0,
        upBound=row.dist_range if np.isfinite(row.dist_range) else None,
    )

df['dist_range'] = df['from'].diff().shift(-1, fill_value=np.inf)
df['distance'] = df.apply(make_distance, axis=1)

distance = df.distance.sum()
cost = df.distance.dot(df.unit_cost)
prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='fixed_budget_max_distance', sense=pulp.LpMaximize)
prob.objective = distance + 0
prob.addConstraint(name='cost', constraint=cost <= 10e3)

print(prob)
prob.solve()
assert prob.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal
print('Can travel up to', distance.value(), 'at cost', cost.value())
print('Distance buckets:')
print(df.distance.apply(pulp.LpVariable.value))
```

```
fixed_budget_max_distance:
MAXIMIZE
1*distance_0 + 1*distance_1 + 1*distance_2 + 1*distance_3 + 1*distance_4 + 0
SUBJECT TO
cost: 25 distance_0 + 27 distance_1 + 29 distance_2 + 31 distance_3
 + 32 distance_4 <= 10000

VARIABLES
distance_0 <= 174 Continuous
distance_1 <= 107 Continuous
distance_2 <= 117 Continuous
distance_3 <= 135 Continuous
distance_4 Continuous

Optimal - objective value 376.2069
Optimal objective 376.2068966 - 3 iterations time 0.002
Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Can travel up to 376.206897 at cost 10000.000013
Distance buckets:
0    174.000000
1    107.000000
2     95.206897
3      0.000000
4      0.000000
```